# Search and select multiple value in listboxt using texboxt

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Hello i'm little new in c# windows form programming
i want to select value from textbox with multiple value like "A,B,C,D" and when i hit search button will select all those value.

i have this code for search single value

```
 for (int i = listBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {

                    if (listBox2.Items[i].ToString().ToLower().Trim().Contains(TxtCariVA.Text.ToLower().Trim()))
                    {
                        listBox2.SetSelected(i, true);
                        listBox2.SetSelected(i - 1, true);
                    }
```

i hope someone can help me

Comment: You haven’t actually asked a question. You want to highlight (select) the list items that contain the values in the text box… Is something not working as expected or do you get an error. The line of code … `listBox2.SetSelected(i - 1, true);` … looks odd and needs clarification. In other words why is the code selecting row `i` AND `i` - 1 … ? … I would think you may get an out of bounds error when `i` = 0. Please [edit] your question to add the problems/issues you are having.

Comment: You are aware that the `Contains` is trying to match the words that contain “a,b,c,d” … ? … Is this the intended search item?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.